# Why onShowFileChooser not working. I cant upload audio file to my webview

Tags: android, file, webview

I'm using android lollipop in my android studio. Whats wrong with my code? anyone please help me! I've been searching any code to upload file in my web view, but still error `onShowFileChooser` is not working. Guys please help me.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  {
WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);


    web = new WebView(this);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()

    {
        //The undocumented magic method override
        //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }




        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                          WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            if (mUploadMessage != null)
            {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }

            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                mUploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


    });
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (mUploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    };




}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

//flipscreen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code

```
package com.inf.os.fileup;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ifView);
        assert webView != null;
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("https://infeeds.com/");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FCR);
            }
            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }
            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
            }
            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: its possible to upload audio file? in my application doesnt need to take a picture or something like that. please help me :(